# Black screen with blinking cursor after fresh Ubuntu server 16.04 install

Tags: server, system-installation, raid

I've tried lots of suggestions:

- I choose "install GRUB on hard disk". Still same problem. The black 
  screen appears after bios screen showing RAID setup. Have Raid 1 set 
  during installation process.
- I tried holding SHIFT to get a Grub menu. Not getting a Grub menu at 
  all.
- I tried pressing CTRL + ALT + F1. Does nothing.
- I also tried SHIFT + ALT + F2. Same, nothing.
- I used the Live USB and choose NOMODESET and boot from disk. Then I get 
  a text 'Boot failed' and a restart with same black screen.
- Deleted and created a new raid. Same blinking cursor.

I am all out of ideas.

CPU T7400.

BIOS Phoenix ver.4 (no menu for efi/legacy)

Comment: does your machine boot properly from the liveCD / usb ?

Comment: Yes. It does. I also tried installing the desktop version. Same problem.